# Есть ли таблица какими цветами подсвечивается код в встроенной Python IDLE?

Tags: python, idle

Мне нужна таблица на подобии:

```
print - фиолетовый
def - оранжевый
название функции - синий
'Текст' - зелёный
```

Есть ли подобная?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, такой таблицы нет, но могу подсказать, где достать все используемые цвета в формате #RRGGBB.

Основные настройки, которые отвечают за цвета в IDLE лежат в `idlelib`

[`idlelib/config-highlight.def`](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/idlelib/config-highlight.def):

```
[IDLE Classic]
normal-foreground= #000000
normal-background= #ffffff
keyword-foreground= #ff7700
keyword-background= #ffffff
builtin-foreground= #900090
...
```

Также в настройках программы можно посмотреть, какой где цвет используется.

[image: IDLE Settings on MacOS]